# Switching variables from columns to rows when using tabstat

Tags: stata

I use the `tabstat` command in Stata 14 and the *community-contributed* `latabstat` command to generate the corresponding `LaTeX` code:

```
tabstat ListOfVariables, stat(count mean sd min max)
```

When `listOfVariables` includes only one variable, the variable shows up in the row and stats show up in columns. However, when there are more than a variable in `listOfVariables`, the variables show up in columns and stats show up in rows. this is particularly bizarre when I have many variables listed in columns.

How can I switch variables from columns to rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use the `columns(statistics)` option of the `tabstat` command:

```
sysuse auto, clear

tabstat price, statistics(count mean sd min max)

    variable |         N      mean        sd       min       max
-------------+--------------------------------------------------
       price |        74  6165.257  2949.496      3291     15906
----------------------------------------------------------------

tabstat price weight mpg rep78, statistics(count mean sd min max)

   stats |     price    weight       mpg     rep78
---------+----------------------------------------
       N |        74        74        74        69
    mean |  6165.257  3019.459   21.2973  3.405797
      sd |  2949.496  777.1936  5.785503  .9899323
     min |      3291      1760        12         1
     max |     15906      4840        41         5
--------------------------------------------------

tabstat price weight mpg rep78, statistics(count mean sd min max) columns(statistics)

    variable |         N      mean        sd       min       max
-------------+--------------------------------------------------
       price |        74  6165.257  2949.496      3291     15906
      weight |        74  3019.459  777.1936      1760      4840
         mpg |        74   21.2973  5.785503        12        41
       rep78 |        69  3.405797  .9899323         1         5
----------------------------------------------------------------
```